# NodeJS: serve png generated by node-canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas

I would like to generate and serve a .png file using node-canvas. Using Express, this is what I have done so far:

**draw_badge.js**

```
function draw() {
  var Canvas = require('canvas'),
      Image = Canvas.Image,
      canvas = new Canvas(200, 200),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.font = '30px Impact';
  ctx.rotate(0.1);
  ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100);

  return canvas;
}

module.exports = draw;
```

**badge.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var draw = require('../lib/draw_badge.js');

router.get('/show', function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  res.end(draw());
});

module.exports = router;
```

But when I go to the route in my browser, I don't see any png. My grasp of node is not firm enough to understand what is going on. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this i**n badge.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var draw = require('../lib/draw_badge.js');

router.get('/show', function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  draw().pngStream().pipe(res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Notice the code `draw().pngStream().pipe(res);`

It will obtain a PNG stream from your Canvas and will pipe this stream to the response stream. Doing things this way, you don't need to call `res.end()`, because when your PNG stream will end, so will your response stream be ended.